# Setting up environment variables for GUI apps?

Tags: macos, customization, environment-variables

Transitioning from Windows to the Mac. In Windows, I had *a lot* of environmental variables set-up that I used to speed up my work. Thinks like

```
DEVDIR=C:\WORKDOCS\DOCS_jaravj\PROJ\dev
DOCDIR=C:\WORKDOCS\DOCS_jaravj
PERS=C:\WORKDOCS\DOCS_jaravj\Personal
PROD=C:\WORKDOCS\DOCS_jaravj\PROJ\PROD
SVN=C:\WORKDOCS\DOCS_jaravj\PROJ\SVN_CO_Tort
```

etc...

That, and the "magic" of autocompletion in the "Run" box and in the file save/open dialogs, allowed me to move around very quickly.

I've set up the equivalent env. variables in the shell, and I can cd and mv etc to the proper directories, but I haven't found a way to do something similar for the GUI apps, so that I can use the same shortcuts in the applications...

I've followed the tips in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x to add the env vars to /etc/launchd.conf but when I am going to save a file (for example), I can't use $PROJ in the "directory selector" and have the file be saved there...

Comment: How would you use a GUI app to call an environment variable? Can you edit in a specific instance how this might work?

Comment: @bmike this is standard OS interaction call the function  getenv() passing the name and it returns the value

Comment: @Mark so this really isn't a user level question since you need to be developing an app to make the call? I'm assuming GUI means cocoa….

Comment: I'll try and take a few screenshots to show what I mean but at the moment I'm a all tied up, so it might take a bit. Basically, to "see" what I mean, define a couple of user env. variables in Windows and then type them in the location bar in Explorer, or in a "save" dialog box - you can do things such as %DOCDIR% <TAB> and it'll auto-complete and suggest alternates from there... Extremely powerful, mouseless way of navigating the system

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe variables set in the environment are going to work in the Open & Save dialog box (OSDB). It's a nice idea, but you'd have to admit, kinda neckbeardy.

The *Macintosh way* would be to use the Favorites list presented on the left of the OSDB. Drag your often used directories there and you have one-click access.

A much more powerful alternative is [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/). This gives you an incredible degree of short-cutting and changes of default behaviors in the OSDB.

Comment: If you test it in Windows, you'll see that you can type in env. vars in any "explorer" dialog, and it'll auto-expand and auto-complete. It's kind of nerdy, but allows you to do all kinds of file management from the command line. Thanks for the tip about DefaultFolder X; other things I miss from OSX are being able to do "file actions" (like open a new folder, delete o rename files) from within the open/save/file dialogues.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use the mentioned environment variables in Save dialogs, you could set up expansion short cuts with a tool like [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/index.html) or [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com) which can expand environment variables to typed text and then use the "Go to Folder" feature (short cut `Apple-G`) (which is available in Save dialogs) to type the locations from the expanded environment variables.

*Note: Be aware that in the current Mac OSX Yosemite, the `launchd.conf` system not works anymore, but there are other ways to achieve the same thing.*